# Unexpected results when merging two vectors into a dataframe

Tags: r

I am extracting data from multiple CSV files and attempting to combine them into a single data frame. The source data is formatted weirdly, so I have to extract the data from specific locations in the source, then place them in a logical pattern in my resulting data frame.

I created two vectors of equal length and pulled the data from my source files. The end result is that I wind up with two vectors of length 3 (as expected), but instead of having a 3x2 data frame (3 observations of 2 variables), I wind up with a 1x6 data frame (1 observation of 6 variables).

What is curious to me is that although RStudio deems them both to be "List of 3", when I show them in the console, they display very differently:

[image: screenshot of console]

The source code which **doesn't** work:

```
#set the working directory to where the data files are stored
setwd("/foo") 

# identify how many data files are present
files = list.files("/foo")

# create vectors long enough to contain all the postal codes and income data
postalCodeData=vector(length=length(files))
medianIncomeData=vector(mode="character", length=length(files))

# loop through all the files, pulling data from rows 2 and 1585.
  for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  x = read.csv(files[i],skip=1,nrows= 1,header=F)
  y = read.csv(files[i], skip = 1584, nrows = 1,header=F)
  postalCodeData[i]=x
  medianIncomeData[i]=y[2]
  }

#create the data frame
Results=data.frame(postalCodeData,medianIncomeData)

#name the columns
names(Results)=c("FSA", "Median Income")
```

My data frame winds up looking like this:

[image: My data frame]

Source code which **does** work:

```
setwd("/Users/Perry/Downloads/Postal Code Data/")
files = list.files("/Users/Perry/Downloads/Postal Code Data/")
postalCodeData=c("K0A","K0B","K0C")
medianIncomeData=c("10000","20000","30000")

Results=data.frame(postalCodeData,medianIncomeData)
names(Results)=c("FSA", "Median Income")
```

Unfortunately, I can't specify the values explicitly because I have a few hundred files to extract the information from. Any advice on how I can correct the loop to get the desired results would be appreciated.

Comment: Those two are not vectors, they are lists. Please, provide some input data easily reproducible, for instance, using `dput`.

Comment: Thanks iled, I went with your improvements. When I comment out the loop, and specify values for my postalCodeData and medianIncomeData directly, I get the expected results, so it seems the loop isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that `medianIncomeData` and `PostalCodeData`, as shown in the first picture, they are lists and not vectors, that is why you see `List of 3`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of "read.csv" is a data frame, so, when you store

```
medianIncomeData[i]=y[2]
```

you are storing a column of a data frame, use

```
medianIncomeData[i]=y[2][1]
```

instead, to store only the value that you want, the same for x

Comment: I get the same results when I specify: `postalCodeData[i]=x[1][1] medianIncomeData[i]=y[2][1]'